# How to fix Google Earth horizon tilt?

Tags: google-earth

How to fix Google Earth horizon tilt?

[image]

I mean, how to drag mouse or what to press, to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

- Use the middle button: Press the middle button and move the mouse forward or back.
- Use the scroll wheel: Press the Shift key and scroll forward or backward to tilt up or down or press the scroll wheel and move the mouse forward or backward.
- Use the left mouse button on Windows & Linux: Press Shift+Left mouse button and drag in any direction. Your mouse will change to crosshairs. Your view will tilt.

Source https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148186?hl=en